# SELECT entries with condition from more than one row

Tags: sql, opensql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
KID       GRP
1         ABS
1         AOR
1         AOR
2         ABS
2         ABS
2         ABS
2         AOR
2         ZVN
3         ABS
```

And I need to find all KID's, which have GRP like ABS and AOR. So the expected result is 1 and 2.

Which SELECT statement can search for this entries?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT KID       
FROM mytable
WHERE GRP IN ('ABS', 'AOR')
GROUP BY KID  
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GRP) = 2
```

The `WHERE` clause filters out any non- `('ABS', 'AOR')` rows. The `HAVING` clause guarantees that only those `KID` values are selected that are associated with *both* `('ABS', 'AOR')`.

Answer (score 1):

One option, using correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT DISTINCT KID       
FROM TableName t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableName t2 
             WHERE t2.GRP='ABS' AND t.KID=t2.KID)
  AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableName t2 
             WHERE t2.GRP='AOR' AND t.KID=t2.KID)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d931b/8/0)</kbd>

Here's a another way using `GROUP BY` which is better if the list grows:

```
SELECT KID       
FROM TableName t
WHERE t.GRP IN('ABS', 'AOR')
GROUP BY KID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.GRP) = 2
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d931b/12/0)</kbd>

Comment: I don't see any aggregate being performed in the query(I think that is where having comes into picture). Do we have any advantage/performance gain when we use having clause instead of where clause? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna: note that i've edited my answer. The `Having` filters the group, the `Where` filters the records before the groups are built.

Comment: Yeah I saw that. Well I still would be glad if my question can be answered.

Comment: Ok Now I get it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. But it won't work if there are more then one entry with KID=1 and GRP='ABS'. I updated the entries in my question so I hope it is more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
select kid from tablename where grp = 'ABS'
intersect
select kid from tablename where grp = 'AOR'
```

You can use `intersect` if your database allows it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of Where and Exists

```
select kid from tablename a where exists
(select 1 from tablename b where b.KID = a.KID and b.GRP = 'ABS')
and GRP = 'AOR'
```

This will also ensure you only get one result for each KID without using `distinct`